# Can't set headers after they are sent without additional res statements

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

Using sailsjs v0.12.1

```
index: function(req, res) {
    Customer.find().populate('projects').exec(function(err, customers) {
        customers.forEach(function(customer, index) {
            customer.projects.forEach(function(project, index) {
                // Find project contributors and attach to project
                ProjectContributor.find({
                    project: project.id
                }).populate('user').exec(function(err, contributor) {
                    project.contributor = contributor;

                    return res.json(customers);
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

This triggers `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`. The interesting thing here is that this error isn't triggered always - everything worked fine ~30 minutes ago.

There's no other `return res.x` statement anywhere else in this controller.

Comment: `res.json()` will be called for each project a customer has.

Comment: You might want to use `async` library and wait till the each customer has been iterated to send the response. As @robertklep said, you are sending json response on each iteration.

Comment: Oh wow, that makes sense! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MjZac do you know any resources on how to do this?

Comment: @nehalist see my answer. It should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the `async` library first.

`npm install async --save`

Then you can use the following code

```
var async = require('async');
// ...
// ...
Customer.find().populate('projects').exec(function(err, customers) {
    var tArray = [];
    async.each(customers, function(customer, cb) {
        var aCustomer = customer; // might want to deep copy it?
        aCustomer.projects = [];
        async.each(customer.projects, function(project, projectCB) {
            ProjectContributor.find({
                project: project.id
            }).populate('user').exec(function(err, contributor) {
                project.contributor = contributor;
                aCustomer.projects.push(project);
                projectCB();
            });
        }, function projectsDone(err) {
            tArray.push(aCustomer);
            cb();
        });
    }, function done(err) {
        return res.json(tArray);
    });
});
```

I haven't tested the code, but it should work just fine.

Comment: I think I get it now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One more question; assuming I'm attaching more than just contributors (e.g. the status, which is calculated by opened and closed issues); do I have to iterate through the projects again with `each` or can this `find` be placed inside the same `each` as the contributors?

Comment: You can place it inside the same `each` as the contributors. Take care to call the `projectCB` after all your operations have been completed in the each statement.

Comment: Since I've drifted away from this problem but recently came back to it; calling `projectCB` multiple times causes a `callback already called` error. Isn't `async.paralell()` here what I need?

Comment: `async.parallel()` takes in an array of tasks to be done in parallel. Maybe you can modify the inner `async.each` and replace it with `async.parallel`. You will still need `async.each` for iterating through the array.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the forEach statement with the each function of the async library (async.each) 
When all the iterations have ended, a callback is called and in that callback you hace to place your res.send() 
[More info here](https://github.com/caolan/async#each)

Comment: The docs say "in paralell". My "inner" `find` is dependent on the "outer" one (I can't find contributors without a project).

Comment: You'll have tu replace both forEach. I dont' see the problem. Every execution of the inner loop will execute in parallel, but I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just had to write your:

```
return res.json(customers);
```

statement at the end of the forEach loop.

Comment: Since the inner loops wouldn't have finished at this point, this would not work at all.